# Che cos'è un "verde smaccato"?

Tags: meaning, adjectives

Nel libro *Racconto d'autunno*, di Tommaso Landolfi, ho letto:

> Mi trovai, dabbasso, in una piccola cantina o canova a volta, che prendeva luce da un'alta feritoia con inferriata,
>   una di quelle, probabilmente, da me rilevate durante il mio esame
>   esterno della casa; in un angolo era un mucchio di patate che levavano alti i loro germogli d'un **verde smaccato**, in un altro non
>   più di cinque o sei mele su uno strato di capecchio.

Ho cercato l'aggettivo "smaccato" in alcuni dizionari e ho visto che significa "esagerato, eccessivo". Tuttavia, non sono sicura di aver capito il senso di "verde smaccato" nel brano precedente. Significa un verde molto vivo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il verde smaccato è il verde chiaro, pallido.

Da un [trattato dell'arte della seta in Firenze](https://ia801201.us.archive.org/27/items/bub_gb_X1DvQTbOu7gC/bub_gb_X1DvQTbOu7gC.pdf):

> Se i verdi chiari prendono nel bagno un brutto colore, si dicono
>   smaccati ; se vengono guasti, cioè anche più brutti, è segno che hanno
>   preso la botta, o la borraccina; vale a dire un colore che non è nè
>   verde nè giallo, partecipando dell’ uno e dell’ altro, proprio come il
>   colore della botta, o della borraccina. E badi che se il verde esce
>   dalla caldaia troppo cupo, noi usiamo dire : ha preso il cipresso.

E dall'indice dello stesso volume:

> VERDE SMACCATO ; è il verde troppo chiaro. 155

I germogli delle patate comuni a pasta bianca sono di colore verde pallido oppure che varia a seconda della tipologia (viola, bianca o rossa)

[image]